# Vertically center list in div

Tags: html, css

I have a div of fixed dimensions and an unordered list inside it. The list's items are positioned horizontally one next to another. What I'm trying to make is a slider that show one list element after another. What I can't do is center the list and the elements vertically inside the div because I don't know the height of the list.

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <ul>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  width: 584px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 3504px;
}

#container ul li {
  width: 584px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Any possible way to do this in CSS?

Comment: Third result on google when I copy pasted your title: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Comment: No can do, sorry. What other info do you need? I'm doing the sliding by changing the left of the ul.

Comment: add for your `ul` `text-align: center;` and set for list elements `display: inline-block`, than remove `float`

Answer (score 1):

I really didn't understand the necessity of overflow hidden and huge width values but I have made what you are expecting.

Using `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` you can align the content to vertically middle.

```
#container {
  width: 584px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
#container ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container ul li {
    width: 100px;
    background:grey; display:table-cell;
    border:white solid 2px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KwdwZ/2/)**